# c# integer operation cause CA2233 overflow warning

Tags: c#, overflow

I have the following code trigger CA2233 warning "Correct the potential overflow in the operation 'latitudeBam*90' in method Foo"

```
double Foo(int latitudeBam)
{
   var latitudeInDegrees = (latitudeBam * 90) / (double)int.MaxValue;
   return latitudeInDegrees; 
}
```

I am not sure where the warning is. is it because latitudeBam can potentially be value close to int.MaxValue, hence overflow int.MaxVlaue, or because something to do with the conversion from int.MaxValue to dobule?

Answer (score 0):

Your first theory is the right one: your calculation may overflow `int.MaxValue` because it multiplies any current int value by 90. In fact, `latitudeBam` could already equal `int.MaxValue` when your method is called.